# What is the correct term for OpenGL's 2x2x2 rendering volume?

Tags: opengl

What do you call OpenGL's 2x2x2 box (in NDC space) where geometry is visible? I'm tempted to call it the NDC frustum, but the term *frustum* seems to be exclusively associated with the visible, pyramid-shaped volume of space after the *perspective* transform has been applied. I understand these volumes map to the same thing, but I want to know if there is an actual term for "the cube where `glPosition` is visible". *Clip space* is also commonly used, but to me this is clearly a type of 3D space, not a cubic portion inside it.

Comment: Clip space is before the perspective divide. NDC after the divide, so they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the 2x2x2, visible volume of NDC space is called? Do you know if there is a term?

Comment: @Andrew There is no word for it other than Normalized Device Space. When you talk about viewing volume, you are talking about a volume in world space or view space. Usually this is either a frustum (perspective projection) or a cuboid (orthographic projection).

Comment: @Andrew: Be advised that the [clipping volume doesn't have to be a cube anymore](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_clip_control.txt), not since GL 4.5 and that extension.

Comment: Thank you @NicolBolas for that link. I read that documentation earlier and couldn't find it today while researching this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally invent words for things because we need to talk about them a lot. The thing is, we don't need to talk about that region of NDC space specifically... because there's nothing outside of it. Ever.

Clipping happens *before* the NDC space transform. And clipping is defined such that no vertices that would fall outside of this region will still exist. That's the whole point of clipping. So the area beyond the NDC-space boundary is always empty.

So it's perfectly fine to think of "NDC space" as specifically the clipped region of it.